# Transferring files from PC to Ubuntu PC on same network

Tags: system-installation, samba

I recently installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 12.04

I wanted to transfer my old files from my PC that is running Windows, to my other PC which now has Ubuntu installed on it.
They are both on the same network, i feel like this should be something easy. to do, but i cant figure it out at all. 
Any help would be appreciated thank you.

I downloaded and installed samba on my Linux computer, and set up a share, but I can not find the directory on my Windows machine. where do I find it?

Comment: You could try going directly to the share by typing the following into the address bar of Windows file browser: \\server\share.

Comment: where do i get the "server" address?

Comment: It's either the local address of your Ubuntu machine or its name, can use either or, no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to share the folders from the Windows machine itself.

How you do that is partially going to depend on whether you're running Windows Home, Windows Pro, or Windows Server.  It's also going to depend on whether you're running XP, Vista or 7, 2003, or 2008.  Once you've got the folder actually SHARED, connecting to it from your Ubuntu PC should be relatively painless.

Comment: i have the folders shared on my windows end, but when i try to access the network on ubuntu  "travis-pc" doesnt seem to show up. hmmph?

Answer (score 0):

In your Windows machine, you should enter the direction of the Ubuntu PC, with this format: `\\IP-ADDRESS`

You can enter this command in the Run menu, open this menu with <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

---

**How do I know what is the IP of the Ubuntu PC?**

Just do click in the Network daemon:

[image: I]

And select ´Connection information´ or similar. Now you will see a window similar then this one:

[image: II]

Where you can see your IP adress.